# replace char in string with "divider"

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace chars in a `String`.
Lets say the string is:

```
"yaaaaaaaay:axaxaxaxa:yaaaaaaay"
```

I want java to change all `a` after the `:` until the next `:` to `X`. So it will look like this:

```
"yaaaaaaaayXxXxXxXxXyaaaaaaay"
```

I tried the following and it did replace all `a` to `X`.

```
public static String replaceMiddle(String input, char divider) {
    return input.replace( "a", "X");
}
```

Comment: Learning Java is annoying since it is strictly a "library" language.  Examine the String API and look for `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do something like this using Regex

```
public static String replaceMiddle(String input, char divider) {    
    String result = input;

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(":(\\w+):").matcher(input);

    if(matcher.find()){         
        String mid = matcher.group(1).replace( "a", "X");

        result = matcher.replaceAll(":" + mid + ":");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Not sure entirely on your use of `divider` but I think you intended to use it like so:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String input = "yaaaaaaaay:axaxaxaxa:yaaaaaaay";

    System.out.println(replaceMiddle(input, ':'));
}

public static String replaceMiddle(String input, char divider) {    
    String result = input;

    String regex = divider + "(\\w+)" + divider;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

    if(matcher.find()){         
        String mid = matcher.group(1).replace( "a", "X");

        result = matcher.replaceAll(divider + mid + divider);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String str ="yaaaaaaaay:axaxaxaxa:yaaaaaaay";
      String[] strarr=str.split(":");
      String str2=strarr[1].replace("a", "X");
      String res=strarr[0]+str2+strarr[2];
      System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Comment: Use `replace()` if you don't need regex.

Answer (score 1):

A short way to achieve that is by doing something like this:

```
String s = "yaaaaaaaay:axaxaxaxa:yaaaaaaay"; 
s = s.replace(s.substring(s.indexOf(":"), s.lastIndexOf(":")),
              s.substring(s.indexOf(":"), s.lastIndexOf(":")).replace("a", "X"));
```

**Output**

```
yaaaaaaaay:XxXxXxXxX:yaaaaaaay
```